# Adding tracks after importing GPS time/position into QGIS?

Tags: qgis

In properties there is "Joins".

I was wondering if this would give me lines linking the points (time order) but can't see how?

Comment: Apart from the time and coordinates do the rows contains any other data - maybe a sequential "id" column?

Answer (score 2):

No, the "Joins" tool won't create a line connecting your points together. ["Joins" creates a table join](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#joins-properties), which adds attributes from another table into the attribute table of the current layer.

**Use the `Points to path` tool to create a line connecting your points together**. `Points to path` is in the Processing Toolbox.

[image]

---

If the GPS points were stored in GPX format, the  original GPX file might have tracks as well. To find out, add the GPX file from the Data Source Manager, and this time when QGIS asks you to "Select vector layers to add...", choose "tracks" instead of "track_points."

[image]

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I should have said that I'm importing a text file with GPS points, altitude, heading, speed etc from an raptor tracker.

I am using Qgis 3.4 Madeira which doesn't seem to have the points to path tool.  I looked at plugins but it's not there either.  Do I have to use an older version to get the tool?

Comment: QGIS 3.4 does have the `points to path` tool. Are you looking in the Processing Toolbox? I added an image to show where to find it.

Comment: As csk said, it's in the Processing toolbox, points to path. Missed it first time around, amongst a lot more other items than I thought.